# Unable to successfully bind an async function to a Leaflet marker popup

Tags: leaflet

I want to create a marker popup filled with content from an AJAX call but I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 does not implement interface Node.`. Here is my code

```js
const foo = L.markerClusterGroup();

records.forEach((r) => {
    const marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(r.lat, r.lng));
    marker.bindPopup(async () => {
        const el = document.createElement('div');
        let html = `<h4>${r.title}</h4>`;
    
        const getData = async (url) => {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            if (response.ok) {
                const json = await response.json();
                html += `<p>${JSON.stringify(json)}</p>`;
                el.innerHTML = html;
                return el;
            }
        };

        const url = `server/foo?id=${r.id}`;
        const div = await get(url);
        console.log(div);
        return div;

    });

    foo.addLayer(marker);
});

map.addLayer(fooLayer);
```

The browser console shows the div with the data, so I am puzzled by the error. I can't figure out what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `async` from the `bindPopup(<fn>)` did the trick. So, the following works. In the end, it was just a timing issue.

```js
marker.bindPopup(() => {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    let html = `<h4>${r.title}</h4>`;

    const getData = async (url) => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (response.ok) {
            const json = await response.json();
            html += `<p>${JSON.stringify(json)}</p>`;
            el.innerHTML = html;
        }
    };

    getData(`server/foo?id=${r.id}`);
    return el;
});
```